# Css gray scale and setting an image on it using :after

Tags: html, css

There is an image with id `img1` and I need to put another image with id `img2` on it. When the mouse is hover on the `#img1` I need it to be black-white but the `#img2` shouldn't be.

This is [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v2h09axr/).

It works but the problem is when the mouse goes over the `#img2` the **grayScale** is removed from the `#img1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```
img:hover {
```

in your css, with:

```
div:hover img {
```

See:

```css
div:hover img {
  filter:gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  background-image: url("http://sk.uploads.im/t/yJtie.png");
  top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: " ";
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.xenergie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-element is sitting on top of the image blocking the hovering of the image.

This can be fixed by applying `pointer-events: none` to the pseudo-element

```
div:after {
  background-image: url("http://sk.uploads.im/t/yJtie.png");
  top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: " ";
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gqwfneq2/)

However, the simplest solution is to change the CSS so that the effect takes place on the div hover not the image.

```
div:hover img {
  filter:gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```css
div:hover img {
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
img {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  background-image: url("http://sk.uploads.im/t/yJtie.png");
  top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: " ";
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.xenergie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://www.xenergie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature.jpg" class="hoverImg" />
  <img src="http://sk.uploads.im/t/yJtie.png" class="absoluteImg" />
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
img {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
div:hover .hoverImg {
  filter:gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.absoluteImg {
  top: 10px;
  right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```